# Wordpress REST API creating pages

Tags: wordpress, api, wordpress-rest-api

Is it possible to set the meta-title and meta-description with the create page call? I can create the page but I don't find the but the possibility to add these fields.

Answer (score 0):

The `meta-title` and `meta-description` are not part of the Wordpress standard, so no, you cannot set them.

Unless you know how they are stored as `postmeta`. WIth `createpage` you can send a `meta` object. See the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/pages/#create-a-page).